# Riemann curvature tensor parallel transport

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

In the Riemann curvature tensor, we are supposed to parallel transport the vectors each step of the way. So when we take the first covariant derivative, won’t that be zero? So aren’t we then taking the second covariant derivative of the zero vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariant derivative is not zero in general. Take for example the plane polar coordinates ($r,\theta$). Of course the curvature tensor is zero for that manifold. But the covariant derivative of a vector $\mathbf V = f(r,\theta)\mathbf e_r + g(r,\theta)\mathbf e_{\theta}$ with respect to $r$ is:
$$\frac{d\mathbf V}{dr} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\mathbf e_r + f \frac{\partial \mathbf e_r}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial r}\mathbf e_{\theta} + g\frac{\partial \mathbf e_{\theta}}{\partial r}$$

The unit vector $\mathbf e_r$ doesn't change when changing $r$, and $$\frac{\partial \mathbf e_{\theta}}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{r}\mathbf e_{\theta}$$
So,
$$\frac{d\mathbf V}{dr} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\mathbf e_r + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r}\right)\mathbf e_{\theta}$$
It is clearly not zero.
The derivative of the vector shown above is: $$lim_{\Delta r \to 0}\frac{\mathbf V(P+\Delta P) - \mathbf V(P)}{\Delta r}$$The difference in the numerator can be visualized taking the arrow in $P$, putting it at $P+\Delta P$, and getting the difference between them. That displacement operation is the parallel transport, which is trivial in this case because there is no doubt of a parallel of a line at a point outside that line. In a curved space, this *parallelism* must be defined.

If we take the derivative of the expression above with respect to $\theta$, the result will be equal to what is obtained by making the derivative with respect to $\theta$ before, and then with respect to $r$. That shows the zero curvature.

Comment: That is what my doubt was, the double covariant derivatives here are not parallel transport after parallel transport right? But it does turn out that the commutator gives the expression which is the difference in parallel transports, which is what confused me. 

The expression doesn’t involve parallel transport anywhere but the result is the same, how come? 

Thank you!

Comment: I edited the answer to detail the parallel transport.